# Has Deadpool ever had telepathy?

Tags: marvel, deadpool

Watching the *Deadpool* movie, and after his mutation, when he's following Vanessa, there seems to be a moment where he's hearing thoughts(hears things but no mouths move). Has he ever been able to read minds?

Comment: He's actually (at least in the main continuity) [telepathically resistant](http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/Psychic_Shield)

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not sure I would call that hearing thoughts, more like hearing **actual** off-screen speech **or** his inner thoughts about what people are thinking when they see his face.

Comment: @Paulie_D: That seems legit.

Comment: Does reading the yellow thought-boxes count as telepathy?

Answer (score -2):

Some were actual speech, but *after* the couple passes him Deadpool keeps hearing things; that's why I believe he has other powers at least in this movie.